# AWS Glue: Maximum needed executors < active executors

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I was looking at my AWS Glue job metrics and found something weird ...

[image]

Why is the number of active executors needed > the maximum needed executors? Why are they not killed?

In Glue at some times as shown in the graph, the number of active executors changes, am I charged based on the number of active executors or what I specified in the job settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The maximum needed executors number is computed from the actively
>   running and pending task counts, so it might be smaller than the
>   number of active executors. This is because there can be executors
>   that are partially or completely idle for a short period of time and
>   are not yet decommissioned.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html

No, you are charged based on number of max DPUs allocated and glue job execution time.